# gtk Linux file manager with column view

Tags: linux, file-management

Is there a Linux file manager or a file manager add-on in gtk with the column view (or something like it) that Apple's *Finder* has?

Here is a screenshot with a short explanation:

[image: Xcode Index Templates Folder Structure]

With the left/right arrow keys, you can navigate to subdirectories or parent directories, and with the up/down keys highlight files.

Comment: Okay, do I see that correctly for each 'right-arrow' you get a new column? Or are there always 4 of them?

Comment: @AngeloNeuschitzer It expands automagically

Comment: do you have a specific reason you want it to be in GTK?

Comment: I just use a gnome-based desktop, and qt and especially tk just don't fit in very well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Marlin](https://launchpad.net/marlin) is an alternative -- it is very fast and looks beautiful:

[image: Marlin UI]

Downside: It is not completely stable, and it has crashed on me now and then.

Answer (score 0):

Pantheon File manager have column view.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:elementary-os/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pantheon-files
```